# Securing the private key utilized by an Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I have an Azure Function that is copying files from a SFTP location to an Azure Blob.
The Private Key / SSH Key needed to establish connection to SFTP is now part of app settings json - as the solution is still constrained to PoC/Development phase.

Before I line this up for Production I have to secure the aforementioned private key.

Is Azure Key Vault an optimal candidate where  I can store the private key. And provision the Azure Function dynamic access to this key via AD ?

Or is there an alternative approach from an Azure PaaS perspective?

Comment: Yes, you could use MSI with Azure function to access to the key vault which stores your private key. Please refer to this [article](https://jan-v.nl/post/using-msi-with-azure-functions-and-key-vault).

Answer (score 1):

I personally have not accessed secrets from the Azure Key Vault from an Azure Function. I find that storing the secrets/keys in the Function App's application settings have suited me just fine thus far.

However, you may find this useful: 
[Retrieve Azure Key Vault Secrets using Azure Functions and Managed Service Identity](https://integration.team/2017/09/25/retrieve-azure-key-vault-secrets-using-azure-functions-managed-service-identity/) After following the steps described at that page to properly set up the vault, you would access from the Function like so:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    SecretRequest secretRequest = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<SecretRequest>();

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(secretRequest.Secret))
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Request does not contain a valid Secret."); 

    log.Info($"GetKeyVaultSecret request received for secret {secretRequest.Secret}");        

    var serviceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(serviceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));            

    var secretUri = SecretUri(secretRequest.Secret);
    log.Info($"Key Vault URI {secretUri} generated");
    SecretBundle secretValue; 
    try
    {
      secretValue = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(secretUri);
    }
    catch(KeyVaultErrorException kex)
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, $"{kex.Message}");
    }
    log.Info("Secret Value retrieved from KeyVault.");

    var secretResponse = new SecretResponse {Secret = secretRequest.Secret, Value = secretValue.Value};

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(secretResponse), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")};


}

public class SecretRequest
{
    public string Secret {get;set;}
}

public class SecretResponse
{
    public string Secret {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
}

public static string SecretUri(string secret)
{
   return $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyVaultUri"]}/Secrets/{secret}";
}
```